# Passing dtexec SSIS package params to SQL execution task(s)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

so I'm pretty new to SSIS here. I have some fields that I'd really like to set globally for my package rather than continuing to finagle with dozens of SSIS tasks. I'm doing this programatically and learned that you can set these calling the package like this:

```
SET @ExecuteStatement=
    'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec /f "\\' + @DBInstance + '\SSIS\Universal.dtsx" 
        /set \Package.Variables[User::Email].Properties[Value]; "' + @Email + '" 
        /set \Package.Variables[User::SSASServer].Properties[Value]; "' + @SSASServer + '"
        /set \Package.Variables[User::MSSQLServer].Properties[Value]; "' + @MSSQLServer + '"
        /set \Package.Variables[User::SSASDatabaseName].Properties[Value]; "' + @SSASDatabaseName + '" 
        /set \Package.Variables[User::LinkedServerAlias].Properties[Value]; "' + @LinkedServerAlias + '" 
        /set \Package.Variables[User::ThreadCount].Properties[Value]; ' + CAST(@ThreadCount AS VARCHAR);


INSERT INTO @LOG
    EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell @ExecuteStatement
```

My understanding is that this will set the scope of those User:: variables at the package level. I have dozens of SQL execution tasks that similarly call SQL scripts that I would really like to pass these params around to. Apparently these SSIS variables get set at run-time, so any sproc that references @[User::Email]  ends up being undefined.

How can I can make sure tasks (execute SQL and mail) have access to these variables so that each package stands alone when being run by users? I'm trying to avoid globals that can be overwritten here so that several people can run it and configure the fields as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally this is achieved using package configurations. Have you checked them out? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx. However this all gets a makeover in SSIS 2012

Comment: I haven't, thank you! Curious, would this be a one config only solution? I was hoping to have a shared field schema so that a packages could run in parallel with different input.

Comment: If you need packages to run in parallel with different parameters then no - config's aren't for you. Do you have an opportunity to upgrade to SQL 2012 at all? I've actually created a tool that lets you mix and match different packages with different parameters and run them in various levels of parallelism. Basically by modelling it in some tables, creating a master package that runs off those tables, and altering child packages to take note of the master package.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and we have SQL Server 2014 now. I've upgraded a lot of our 2008 packages to 2012. Figures hooking into older logic wouldn't go anywhere, but my knowledge is obviously lacking here. That parent-child package methodology sounds perfect if it avoids the static config issue.

Comment: Take it this heavily depends on the new 2012 package parameters too then? And I mainly using SQL execution tasks referencing sprocs with occasional mail tasks, so I'm not afraid to do a lot in SQL. Would you mind also speaking to how you would run another package/pass data without relying on environmental variables? It sounds like your configuration would dovetail the parent package configuration. My use use case is probably specific here, but I'd it if people were able to run packages from any computer without worrying about minutiae detail like how a registry is configured.

Comment: OK so I'll explain a little more about what I built in SQL 2008: 1. A table listing all packages (populated by xp_cmdshell); 2. A table listing 'run profiles' which are a combination of a list of packages and the standard parameters to run them underas well as a 'run group' indicating which ones should run in parallel.; 3. A master package which takes a run profile code on the command line, reads the parameters and package lists for this run profile, loads the packages dynamically into execute package tasks. 4. parameters need to be standardised in the master and child packages

Comment: The other pieces were a logging table, written to by the master package to indicate package start and end, a bunch of SQL Jobs to run it all and a nifty MS Access front end that lets you configure, start, and observe package execution.

Comment: The first step is to go through your packages, ensure variables are consistently named and typed, and to configure every package to load those variables from the master package. When they are run standalone this does nothing but when run from a master package they inherit the values

Comment: and looking at my code there's also another bit that crawls through the packages and writes the package version and the tables it uses into a metadata table.